# Xp bsod on startup after ram upgrade

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, memory, bsod

I just upgraded my hp dv6426us from 1gb of ram (512x2) to 4 gb (2x2). I have a vista 32 bit and xp 32 bit dual boot os configuration.

Now when I boot up xp gives me a bsod right after showing the spalsh screen. It does this in safe mode too. However, Vista works fine. The bios shows 4096mb of ram. Vista System information shows:
Installed physical memory (RAM): 4.00 GB
Total physical memory: 2.99 GB

I would like to be able to use xp with 4 gb of ram, or at least the 3 gb it cuts it down to (if it does.) I would *not* like to go back to using 1 gb. Any suggestions?
Thanks!

EDIT:
the bsod shows:

A problem has been detected and windows has been shut down to prevent damage to your computer. If this is the first time you've seen this stop error screen, restart your computer. If this screen appears again, follow these steps:

Check for viruses on your computer. Remove any newly installed hard drives or hard drive contollers. Check your hard drive to make sure it is proberley configured and terminated.
Run CHKDSK /F to check for hard drive corruption, and then restart your computer

Technical information:

*** STOP: 0x0000007B (0xBA4CF524,0xC0000034,0X00000000,0x00000000)

also, memtest86 results are no errors

Comment: do a boot logging with the XP, then hop from the vista and read where the bootlog ends.  It can help to clear the prefetch folder for boot logging. I think i have seen this with a video driver, if only i could remember, it might be a thing to disable (run in copmpatability) first to test, because of the "way" they use that memory spaces.  Safe isnt very safe (even back in xo) many of the high end drivers are set to run as safe.  also, You should still do a memtest86 with a boot disk, but from what your saying that isnt As Nessisary.  It is likely to be a driver item,

Comment: Ok, I will learn about bootlogging and attempt to do one right now! Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: Chances are good this is fixable.  If you can you want to bootlog the old way (where it worked) then bootlog with it failing, it will save a lot of time seeing what is the next item in the bootlog , where it faild.

Comment: ok... so you mean do a bootlog first with 1 gb of ram, then do one with the 4 gb?

Comment: That is correct. When it fails, the bootlog may or may not show the item is was about to load at that time.  The working bootlog would show everything.

Comment: ok, just enabled boot logging in xp. it bsod and restarted. Now i am booting into vista to check the log.

Comment: ok, how do i read "bootstat.dat"? I can not open it with notepad

Comment: BootLog.txt is what your looking for.

Comment: i see no file called bootlog.txt

Comment: My problem looks like it cannot write the file because it crashes before any drivers get loaded

Comment: That could very well be.   Debugging mode would step by step through the failing process, it would give you a better idea of when it bails out.

Comment: Debugging mode gives a bsod too :(

Comment: It will, it isnt "safe" it steps slower.  Did it show you any text that might be usefull in diagnosing the issue? (it would rarely show the thing causing the fail)   Could you put the Error and the number of the BSOD into the question.

Comment: I am gone now. Last thoughts. When the system is operational (1gig mem) "system configuration" Msconfig.exe could also assist in reducing the boot stuff.  In Boot tab "[X} Base video" , In service tab, Hide all microsoft then disable all 3rd party, in Startup tab disable all.  In the "device manager", disable video driver (temporarily) also other large 3rd party driver items you might suspect.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the problem is not with boot items. (it is an almost fresh os with no recently installed items.) bsod is now in the question

Comment: Correct again, that error is when the hard drive is an issue, Which in the case could be caused by a real memory problem, also could have already been caused, meaning the disk may need to be chacked before it is assumed that it is fully bootable.  Memtest, then check the disk.

Comment: sorry, how do i do memtest? can I do it from a 3rd party app in vista?

Comment: nevermind. figured out how to run memtest. will try now

Comment: sorry that took me so long. just ran memtest86 and the results are "no errors" Any idea what could be causing the blue screen? does xp just not like 4gb of ram? should I run the computer with 1x2gb and 1x512mb?

Comment: 32bit XP is very happy with what is left of 4gigs the addition of the stop error code improves the question by a lot.

Comment: but xp does not look happy. It should be, but it is still giving me a stop error.

Comment: 1. Since you boot to Vista too, you probably have bcd.
Can you post here the results of BCDEdit from vista?
If I recall correctly you can limit the the memory your OS can see through there.
2. Try deleting pasgefile.sys from the XP partition, and try booting - it's a long shot but doesn't hurt to try.
3. Try booting with one 2GB memory stick, and tell us how it goes.

Comment: Could you check if SATA mode in BIOS is set to AHCI. To boot xp it should be set to ATA.

Comment: if you take out the recently upgraded memory sticks and put back the old replaced memory sticks, do you still receive the stop 7b bsod?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was away from home.
Gladiator2345: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! Please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as accepted. When I was changing the ram, I disconnected the cmos battery just to be safe. This must have reset the bios changing back to sata enabled mode that I forgot I had disabled to allow xp to run. It's just like me to forget the most obvious things :P
Xp sys information even recognizes 4gb of ram (although it only shows 2.64 as "available" task manager says 3gb total. Whatever the case, performance is now stunningly better. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this fix was originally suggested in a comment by gladiator2345. I am now posting it as the answer since he did not.

gladiator2345 said:

> Could you check if SATA mode in BIOS is set to AHCI. To boot xp it should be set to ATA

When I was changing the ram, I disconnected the cmos battery just to be safe. This must have reset the bios changing back to sata enabled mode that I forgot I had disabled to allow xp to run. 
It's just like me to forget the most obvious things :P Xp sys information even recognizes 4gb of ram (although it only shows 2.64 as "available" and task manager says 3gb total. Whatever the case, performance is now stunningly better.

Thank you once again gladiator2345

Answer (score 3):

[STOP 0x0000007B](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324103) normally means "INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE",
which means that the crash on XP
happens very early in the boot process.

This stop-code actually means : Something prevented protected-mode (meaning XP boot) from connecting to the device that the real-mode (meaning BIOS) passed on to protected-mode.
Said device is most probably the hard disk.

One guess to the problem could be that it has to do with the BIOS seeing your additional RAM but somehow later miscommunicating with the XP boot process.

In that case, I suggest as a first step to update your BIOS from the page
[HP Pavilion dv6040us Notebook PC Drivers](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?product=3210685&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&lang=en&cc=us),
then try again to boot.
Ensure that your computer model is exactly the same as described on that page and
that your BIOS is not already of that version (so as not to take this risk for nothing).
Stop on the least doubt or error message, since a botched BIOS update can brick your computer.

If this doesn't help, start XP with 1 GB and fully patch it using Windows Update, including optional updates. Check in the above HP download page if any drivers
are more recent than the ones Windows suggested, with special attention to
the chipset and storage drivers.

If this doesn't help, setup the computer with 4 GB and try to do a [Repair Installation](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/operatingsystems/ss/instxprepair1.htm)
for XP.
This requires an XP boot CD, but read well on all the requirements in this article.

All backups need to be done before starting, as this kind of operations could result in
a total reinstallation of all operating systems.

Comment: about flashing the bios. The bios update says for systems with AMD processors. I have an intel core 2 duo. should I just proceed with the next steps then?

Comment: NO! Get in touch with HP Support first. A botched BIOS upgrade can only be fixed by a professional. Normally the update itself will not work under the wrong conditions, but don't count on it.

Comment: See if this HP article can help in locating a suitable BIOS update: [Updating the BIOS](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c00007682).

Comment: yeah, I get the severity of a botched bios. I meant the steps suggested after the bios update. Thanks for the suggestion of getting in touch with hp. The only problem is that the computer is no longer under warranty. any other way to contact hp?

harrymc, thanks for the artical

Comment: I think warranty is required only for repairs, not to only get a download link. You could also try the [HP Support Forums](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/).

Comment: harrymc, The link you gave me was to the wrong page (not your fault, I gave you the wrong model number :P) I have updated the model number in the description. drivers should be avalible here: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&os=228&product=3439463&sw_lang=&

however, there is no xp operating system here. I think when I installed drivers for xp, I used the drivers indended for hpdv6000 CTO avalible here:
http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=228&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=1842155#N1408

CONTINUED IN NEXT COMMENT

Comment: so might my problem be that xp is not supported by this computer? But it still ran before the ram upgrade... Should I try installing the bios update for the hp dv6426us and see if it fixes the problem?

Comment: The Vista BIOS "should" work from Vista, but better take precautions. Try to create a boot CD or USB that contains WinFlash and the old BIOS and ensure that it boots and that WinFlash starts to work. To obtain the current BIOS, see [Universal BIOS Backup Toolkit](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/9856-Universal-BIOS-Backup-Toolkit) and [this thread](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-Systems-and-Software/How-do-I-export-backup-the-BIOS-for-my-HP-DV6T-laptoop/td-p/1759655). Be very methodical and careful, and ensure that you know of a good repairman before starting.

Comment: Before starting, check that the BIOS on the download page is not already the one that is installed.

Comment: ok. Thanks for the tip. That would be a bummer to take such a risk to install the same version :P Are there other steps I can take first before going to such drastic measures such as updating the bios?

Comment: That's all the precautions I take myself. I never had a BIOS update go bad on me, the only case I encountered was on this forum and the person there did continue in spite of a compatibility warning by the flash utility. If HP haven't messed up, this should go without a hitch. Check the BIOS version carefully if it's not already installed or even if yours is more recent (HP can make mistakes).